# Minicom showing garbage characters

Tags: linux, serial-port, minicom

I am developing a program for an IP camera and when I tried connecting my device's serial console through minicom, I got the following prints.

```
~ # ls                                                                          
a.txt  4[1;34metc  ���j�����m�ڵ����ښ�j���٥�m�ڵ����ښ�j�ɽ�m�ڵ����ښ�j ѵ
�m�ڵ5R�ڴ�ښ�j���m�ڵ� �1;36minit  ��ښ�j���m�ѵ���ښ�j��ٕ�ɱ��mڵ嵁���ښ�j�ɽ�
m�ѵ�� �1;34musr                                                               
dev   ���Ś�j���m�ڵ���ښ�j���呱���m�ڵ��ڴ�ښ�j��ɽ�m�ڵ���L�&SkW�mm͵���ښ�jم
�m�ɵ5R��
```

This is happening only for multi-column prints and not for single-column outputs.

```
# find . -name "*"                                                         
.                                                                               
./adduser                                                                       
./amixer                                                                        
./aplay                                                                         
./arecord                                                                       
./arp                                                                           
./arping                                                                        
./ash                                                                           
./awk                                                                           
./basename
```

I have set the correct baud rate and parameters: 57600 and 8-N-1. Any suggestions why this is happening would be appreciated.

Comment: Psrt of the problem is likely the terminal emulation. (eg ansi/vt100, but im not an rxpert here - its just some of the chars remind me of old bbs codes)

Comment: Try `man ls` -> `ls --color=never`, (I suspect that it isn't enough). Do you have `od` or `xxd` available? If not can you dump the output to a file?4